# scrollTop not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

This snippet of code works in firefox but not in chrome it doesn't scroll - the click event fires but won't even go to its position on the anchor tag.

```
$(function() {
$(".menu li a").click(function(e) {
    var value = $(this).attr('href');
    var id = value.substr(1, $(this).attr('href').length);              
    var px = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') > -1 ? 16 : 1;
    var target = $("a[name=" + id + "]").offset().top + px;

    console.log( $("a[name=" + id + "]"));

    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: target + 'px'
    }, 'slow');

    e.preventDefault();

});
```

})

Answer (score 1):

`scrollTop` should be [set with an integer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop), try not adding `+ 'px'`.

For example, this will work:

```
$('html, body').stop().animate({scrollTop: 100}, 'slow');
```

If it doesn't for you then something else on the page is blocking scrolling, or your body/html doesn't have a scroll height bigger than the browser window.

You can further test with vanilla JavaScript by typing `document.body.scrollTop = 200;` in the console. If *that* doesn't scroll your page then something else is definitely wrong. Perhaps a Chrome Extension?

(Also firefox UA sniffing looks like trouble, but no one asked me :))

Comment: Yeah I removed that and just put a number like 1000 and the page won't scroll